# JQuery rotate - re-initiate rotation in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a circular image that rotates on page load and stops and starts on mouseover/out.   The circle is also draggable so that I can manually spin it.  This all works fine in Mozilla, but doesn't work so well in Chrome.  The problem is that it doesn't re-initiate the `rotateCircle();` on mouseout.  can anyone help find out why this is?  I am using `jQueryRotate` and `Greensock Draggable` for this.

```
$(function() {

    var angle = 0;
    var int;
    rotateCircle();

    function rotateCircle() {
        int = setInterval(function() {
            angle += 3;
            $("#circle").rotate(angle);
        }, 100);
    }           

    $("#circle").mouseover(function() {
        clearInterval(int);
        Draggable.create("#circle", {type:"rotation",throwProps:true});
    }).mouseout(function() {
       rotateCircle();
    });



});


</script>
```

Comment: its mostly because you are using 2 libraries for rotating the same element so in chrome GreenSock uses the css3 transform property and jQuery rotate uses -webkit-transform property

Comment: Ah ok.  Any ideas on a solution?  I need the two libraries as they both do different things. thanks

Comment: here's how i did it using jquery transit, vector math & livescript http://codepen.io/furqanZafar/pen/myeXPo

Comment: That works great, but looks quite advanced for me.  I can't really use it if I don't understand it, would prefer to find a solution to get the above working together if possible.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way is to add a rotateBy method to the GreenSock Draggable class.

Here is the updated Draggable class:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furqanZafar/GreenSock-JS/master/src/uncompressed/utils/Draggable.js

I only added the following method to Draggable.js:

```
this.rotateBy = function(amount) {
    self.rotation += amount;
    self.x = self.rotation;
    dirty = true;
    render();
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle that works on both chrome & ff using the new Draggable class: http://jsfiddle.net/58rauhsL/

```
$(function() {

    var draggable = Draggable.create("#circle", {type:"rotation",throwProps:true}), 
        interval;

    function rotateCircle() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            draggable[0].rotateBy(3);
        }, 100);
    }

    rotateCircle();

    $("#circle").mouseover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        rotateCircle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand why Javascript is required for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/nmmkLpqo/ (example only for chrome, add vendor-prefixes for FX etc.)

```
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 5s linear infinite;
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

This should do exactly the same?

Comment: I would have used that if I hadn't used the draggable plugin, thanks